# Thunderbird 5.0 minimize to tray?

Tags: thunderbird

I just upgraded to thunderbird 5.0 and I noticed that my minimize to tray plus does not work with thunderbird 5.0

is there any other plugins that do the same thing? Kinda sucks that still in 5.0 it is not a standard feature.

Comment: Have you considered submitting a feature request to the maker of the current plugin you use?

Comment: for which OS do you want that feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MinimizeToTray revived](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-revived/) works for me in 5.0.

Comment: Any idea when this will work with 6.0? I don't like this new release schedule. Seems to screw around with the plugins(what makes their programs good)